# Keras dropping dimension in LSTM, not sure why

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Following up to [Keras LSTM Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504098/keras-lstm-input-0-of-layer-sequential-10-is-incompatible-with-the-layer?noredirect=1#comment117573961_66504098)

I now have the following code:

```
def myLSTM(i_shape, o_shape):
  input = keras.layers.Input(i_shape)
  print(input)
  model = Sequential()
  x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True, input_shape = [1, x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1]])(input)
  x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
  x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True)(x)
  x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
  x = keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True)(x)
  x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
  output = keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation='softmax')(x)
  print('input: ', input)
  print('outpput: ', output)
  return keras.Model(input, output)

print(x_train.shape)
my_lstm = myLSTM(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
my_lstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
my_lstm.summary()
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_22: expected shape=(None, 25000, 100), found shape=(None, 100)
```

I'm not sure why it dropped the 25000 from the dimensions. I have printed out the input variable in the first line and it is of dimension (None, 25000, 100)

Comment: You need input shape of `(25,000, 1, 100)`

Comment: Why not [1, 25000, 100]? I thought batch size is first right?

Comment: x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))(input)

Comment: I tried this but it still did not work ^^

Comment: `input_shape` should not include the batch dimension at all. Just `(sequence_length, number_of_features)`.

Comment: @xdurch0 I tried this out:  ```  x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1]))(input) ```

Comment: It still shows this error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_4: expected shape=(None, 207, 20), found shape=(None, 20)

Comment: No, axis 0 is the batch axis, so you have to omit that one. Try `input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]`